# Sort partitions with several criteria

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I try to sort partitions with several criteria.

With this query, I have the following output:

```
SELECT id, aggregate_id, aggregate_update, detection_time
FROM report.report_table R1
WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'AGGREGATE_ALERT_EVENT'
ORDER BY MAX(aggregate_update)
OVER (PARTITION BY aggregate_id) ASC,
  aggregate_id, aggregate_update asc, detection_time desc;
```

[image: partition sorted by aggregate_update but not detection_time]

We see that the rows are partitioned by aggregate_id. Inside each partition, the rows are sorted firstly by aggregate_update ASC, and then by detection_time DESC. However, the partitions are sorted only by MAX(aggregate_update), and I want the partition sorted by MAX(aggregate_update) and MAX(detection_time) DESC. I try to get the following result:

[image: partition sorted by aggregate_update but and detection_time]

How can I sort the partitions themselves between them with several criterias ?

Comment: Why would `ORDER BY aggregate_id, aggregate_update, detection_time DESC` not work here?  If that wouldn't work, then maybe add some sample data which explains it.

Comment: A simple ORDER BY aggregate_id ASC will display the A6 before the A7. I need to add MAX(aggregate_update) OVER (PARTITION BY aggregate_id) ASC first but I would like to take into accound the detection_time as well for the partitions

Comment: OK, but why does `A1` appear before both `A6` and `A7`, given that the latter two have _greater_ aggregate update times?  You need to explain your logic better.

Comment: It is because of the line ORDER BY MAX(aggregate_update) OVER (PARTITION BY aggregate_id) ASC. The aggregate_update is sorted in ascending order so A1 is always before A6 and A7. A6 and A7 have the same aggregate_update, so it is then the detection_time which should be decisive, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should give you the behavior you want:

```
SELECT id, aggregate_id, aggregate_update, detection_time
FROM report.report_table R1
WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'AGGREGATE_ALERT_EVENT'
ORDER BY
    MAX(aggregate_update) OVER (PARTITION BY aggregate_id),
    MAX(detection_time) OVER (PARTITION BY aggregate_id) DESC,
    aggregate_id,
    detection_time DESC;
```

The second sorting condition I added breaks the tie should two `aggregate_id` groups happen to have the same maximum update value.  In this case, the sort falls back to whichever group has the greater detection time to decide which comes first.